# Play sound at specific time when app is in background mode (iOS 7)

Tags: background, nsdate, alarm, audio

I need to play sound at specific hours like alarm clock app, for example at 17:30, 18:00, 20:00, etc. I'm tried with UILocalNotifications but don't have sufficient options to customize all of I need.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible — the only way to trigger a user stimulus when your application is not the firstresponder is to register a notification.

[Check this out for more information on Push and Local Notifications.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)

What customizations are you trying to make? iOS notifications are not terribly versatile, but it is possible to customize the message and sound, among a few other things.